# Delete or Remove Created Table with iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I've been looking for sometime now and am unable to see how do delete a created table using iTextSharp. Long story short I'm looking at page numbers and need to delete the current table if the page number changes. The PdfPtable has a property to delete rows, but when I use that nothing seems to happen.

```
Private Sub CreatePDFDocument_AddTitleTable(ByRef targetDocument As Document, ByVal TargetString As String)

    Dim table As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(1)
    table.WidthPercentage = 100.0F
    table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
    table.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE
    table.DefaultCell.PaddingTop = 6
    table.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 11
    table.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = ColorDark

    table.AddCell(New Paragraph(New Chunk(TargetString, Font12Bold)))

    targetDocument.Add(table)

    '// Testing to Delete

    table.DeleteBodyRows() '// Does nothing
    table.DeleteLastRow() '// Does nothing
    table.DeleteRow(0) '// Does nothing

End Sub
```

I was hoping for something like the below, but I've read through all of the properties and nothing seems to indicate deletion for the table.

```
table.Delete
table.Remove
```

Any help would be appropriated, I'm working in VB.Net but I understand C#. If deleting the table is not possible, my alternative would be to build a brand new document every time the page number changes

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to first add some table to a document (`targetDocument.Add(table)`) and thereafter change the table in that document. That is not easily possible in general: when you add a table to a document, a wild collection of text pieces, lines, etc. is added to the content of the current page, probably backed by arbitrary material added by table events. And all that is not linked to the `table` object instance anymore.

Comment: I see, what you have said makes sense. I was sort of envisioning the PDF editing to be like a word document in a way. I think I have worked out a work around now anyway, I am going to measure the purposed table against what is remaining in the PDF sheet and see if it will fit on the same page, if it doesn't then the table doesn't get added. Thanks for your reply!